# Variable Undefined In Namespace

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following set of files.

```
// HeaderOne.h
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        class A
        {
            .
            .
            .
        };
    }
}

// HeaderTwo.h
namespace foo
{
    namespace bar
    {
        std::string const baz;
    }
}

// HeaderTwo.cpp
#include "HeaderTwo.h"

using namespace foo::bar;

std::string const baz = "baz";

// HeaderOne.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "HeaderOne.h"
#include "HeaderTwo.h"

using namespace foo::bar;

A::A()
{
    std::cout << baz << std::endl;
}
```

I am using CMake as my build system and when I build, I get an undeclared identifier error on `baz`. I would think this should work, but any changes I make seem to still produce errors between definitions split among the files. Any ideas what might be going wrong here?

Comment: You have to put your definitions inside the namespaces like on the headers, not just use `using namespace`

Comment: Or `foo::bar::A::A() {}`

Comment: Don't you get a "*reference to 'baz' is ambiguous*" error (because you define two different `baz`s)? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You likely want only to **declare** `baz` in `HeaderTwo.h`, but you actually define it, which then breaks ODR. You might want to use `extern` there. And, in `HeaderTwo.cpp`, you define another `baz` in a global namespace, which again likely you don't want to. Use `foo::bar::baz =` instead.

Comment: @A. A I tried that. I also tried the alternative of prefixing my variable with the full namespace path `foo::bar::baz` and get the same issue.

Comment: @RustyX I'm a little confused by your comment. The code I have posted above is minimal and complete to reproduce this issue for me. Check my update I am posting as that takes in some fixes suggested here. And no I do not get an ambiguous error. The exact error is `undeclared identifier baz`

Comment: @Daniel Langr I see what you are saying. I implemented your suggestion, but still get the error.

Comment: Posing updated code

Comment: I have to retract my statement. Doing what was described in the selected answer worked. I cleaned out my build directory and did a fresh build and it worked with the change in the suggested answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define something, use this form.

```
namespace name{
     type definedname= value;
}
```

Or

```
     type name::definedname= value;
```

Otherwise how could compiler know which namespace the definedname should be put under. It will put under no namespace.